# In Python a function is running, but it was never called. How is that possible

Tags: python, multithreading, function, server

I'm currently working with the following code to set up an application that will be running on a Raspberry Pi. Setting it up to have remote access to the application for input and output manipulation. I'm trying to understand what is happening here, before I start writing the code I need for my project.

```
import socket
import threading

...

class chatServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, (socket, address)):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket
        self.address = address

    def run(self):
        lock.acquire()
        clients.append(self)
        lock.release()
        print '%s:%s connected.' % self.address
        while True:
            data = self.socket.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            for c in clients:
                c.socket.send(data)
        self.socket.close()
        print '%s:%s disconnected.' % self.address
        lock.acquire()
        clients.remove(self)
        lock.release()


while True:  # wait for socket to connect
    # send socket to chatserver and start monitoring
    chatServer( s.accept() ).start()
```

What I don't understand is how it works. So obviously threading is going on, a single fork that ends with the main thread sitting waiting for any new connections to be made to the server. The new thread loops inside the "while True:" statement inside "def run(self): function.

But why does the 2nd thread hang out in the "while True:" loop? The "def run(self) function was never called, so why is it running?

Comment: The `start()` method of a `Thread` object starts the thread and returns immediately, so your `while True` loop that starts the `chatServer`, will forever continue starting new `chatServer` threads. And your code is waiting on the `s.accept()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the '**class chatServer(threading.Thread)**:' you said to Python that the class *chatServer* will inherit the methods of *threading.Thread*, that is, all methods in *threading.Thread* will be "copied" for chatServer.

If you want, you can check the methods contained in a class by typing dir(class).

dir(threading.Thread)

`['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_bootstrap', '_bootstrap_inner', '_delete', '_exc_info', '_initialized', '_reset_internal_locks', '_set_ident', '_set_tstate_lock', '_stop', '_wait_for_tstate_lock', 'daemon', 'getName', 'ident', 'isAlive', 'isDaemon', 'is_alive', 'join', 'name', 'run', 'setDaemon', 'setName', 'start']`

As you can see, the threading.Thread has two peculiar methods: **run** and **start**.

In your case, the run method inherted was overwrited by you when you create the def run()... However, the method start still remain in the class chatServer, check it by typing dir(chatServer) in your console. That method start has a callable `__call__`  that call, doh', the method run(self) in their class. So, that is why it is running.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for creating a running thread

1. pass a *callable* to the thread constructor (either a function, or an object that has a `__call__` method)
2. pass an object of a class that subclasses `Thread` (that's your case). In this case, the `run()` method of the object is called when the thread starts. That a design choice (it has to run *something*), and it is similar in other languages

Official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html#thread-objects